# iOS Unexpected platform condition (expected 'os', 'arch', or 'swift') - Reachability

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, reachability, reachability-swift

I just update my pods. after update `Reachability` causing an error

> Unexpected platform condition (expected 'os', 'arch', or 'swift')

I tried to build and clean but it does not work. what's the solution?
[image: Here's Screenshot]

Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `#if targetEnvironment` is a new feature of Swift 4.1/Xcode 9.4(?). Probably you are using an older version.

Comment: I am using Xcode 9, swift 4.0

Comment: ... that explains it.

Comment: But I can't update to it Xcode 10, what the solution?

Comment: use this instead of the 1 u r trying.

#if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)

#endif

Comment: Use a previous release - v4.1.0 should work for you

Answer (score 1):

use this 1

```
#if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)

#endif
```

Comment: Hello, to help others understand your answer, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as Muhammad says.

I suggest the following code which is very easy to maintain. Copy paste the following code to a file and try yourself.

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

class Network {

    // Declarations
    static let shared = Network()


    // Check has Network
    func isConnected() -> Bool  {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }

        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }

}
```

Create a swift file and put the above code on that file.
Whenever you want to check the network status just use the following code

```
if Network.shared.isConnected() {

   print("Network available")
} else {

   print("Not connected")
}
```