# iOS - Type 'UIView' has no member 'AnimationOptions'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I am using **TextFieldEffects** to add text inputs effects in my textField. it is showing an error

> Type 'UIView' has no member 'AnimationOptions'

Here's code.

```
override open func animateViewsForTextEntry() {
    borderLayer.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: font!.lineHeight)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.3, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.beginFromCurrentState, animations: ({

        self.placeholderLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.placeholderInsets.x, y: self.borderLayer.frame.origin.y - self.placeholderLabel.bounds.height)
        self.borderLayer.frame = self.rectForBorder(self.borderThickness, isFilled: true)

    }), completion: { _ in
        self.animationCompletionHandler?(.textEntry)
    })
}

override open func animateViewsForTextDisplay() {
    if text!.isEmpty {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 2.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.beginFromCurrentState, animations: ({
            self.layoutPlaceholderInTextRect()
            self.placeholderLabel.alpha = 1
        }), completion: { _ in
            self.animationCompletionHandler?(.textDisplay)
        })

        borderLayer.frame = rectForBorder(borderThickness, isFilled: false)
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the error.
[image: Here's a screenshot of the error.]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: `UIView.AnimationOptions.beginFromCurrentState` compiles without problems  in Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10). Are you using an older version?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9 and Swift 4.0

Comment: It is the same problem as in your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52523952/1187415: You try to compile Swift 4.2 code with Xcode 9.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `UIViewAnimationOptions.beginFromCurrentState`, at least in Xcode < version 10.

Comment: Usually the compiler is smart enough to infer the type, so you can use     `. beginFromCurrentState` and skip the prefix. (That has the advantage of being the same in Xcode 9.x and 10.x.)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `UIView.AnimationOptions.beginFromCurrentState` to `[.beginFromCurrentState]`.

Comment: The braces aren't needed if you only provide one flag. In that case `[.beginFromCurrentState]` and `.beginFromCurrentState` are interchangeable.